# Violating polymorphism by having base ViewModel class determine current type?

Tags: c#, wpf, polymorphism

I have a base ViewModel that has a public method. Things were pretty simple at first and its role was the same for all of its derived classes, but now we want the ViewModel to do different things depending on which derived class calls it.

So for example we have:

```
    public void DoMethod()
    {
        DoThisMethod();
    }
```

we want something like

```
    public void DoMethod()
    {
        if (this.GetType().Name == "ThisName")
           DoThisMethod();
        else
           DoAnotherMethod();
    }
```

Is it wrong to do this?

Comment: In addition to @Ehsan's answer. You can also check that whether you need a default implementation of the method or not.If not, you should mark method & view model as 'abstract' & override the method,this way every inherited class will be forced to define an implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the solution that you propose is wrong for a design point of view. Your base class should be agnostic of the inherited type "ThisName". Using your naming you could resolve your problem by implementing it in this way:

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public virtual void DoMethod()
    {
        DoAnotherMethod();
    }

    public void DoAnotherMethod() {...}
}

public class ThisName: ViewModel
{
    public override void DoMethod()
    {
        DoThisMethod();
    }

    public void DoThisMethod() {...}
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This is a perfect scenario for using [Method Overriding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebca9ah3.aspx).

You should be using **OOP** concept of method overriding here:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
   public virtual void DoMethod()
   {
        DoThisMethod();
   }
}
```

and now when you inherit some class from `BaseViewModel`, you can define different implement of `DerivedViewModel` using overrding:

```
public class DerivedViewModel:BaseViewModel
    {
       public override void DoMethod()
       {
            // implementation here
       }
    }
```

Now when you will call it using `DerivedViewModel` object it will the implementation of `DoMethod()` defined in `DerviedViewModel` type.

If you don't have access to implementation of `BaseViewModel` then you will have to use Shadowing Concept:

```
public class BaseViewModel
{
   public void DoMethod()
   {
        DoThisMethod();
   }
}
```

and in Derived Type:

```
public class DerivedViewModel:BaseViewModel
{
    public new void DoMethod()
   {
        DoThisMethod();
   }
 }
```

But generally it is not considered good to use Shadowing.

You may read more about method overriding [in this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18734/Method-Overriding-in-C)